# How can I get rid of `unwrap()` from rust code?

Tags: rust

```rust
//https://lib.rs/crates/curl
fn main() {
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://www.rust-lang.org/").unwrap();
    easy.write_function(|data| {
        stdout().write_all(data).unwrap();
        Ok(data.len())
    }).unwrap();
    easy.perform().unwrap();

    println!("{}", easy.response_code().unwrap());
}
```

the `unwrap()` exists almost in every line of the code and makes me dizzy when reading the code.

I really don't like it, how can I remove it?

Comment: Just handle the appropriate error cases. And in the future use `cargo clippy` with the additional `--unwrap-used` flag to identify problematic lines in your code.

Comment: I think somebody wrote a [chapter about error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) into "The Rust Programming Language"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Result<U,E>::and_then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) allows you to combine a sequence of `Result`s from each call in a dependent way:

```
fn main() {
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://www.rust-lang.org/")
    .and_then(|_| {
        easy.write_function(|data| {
        stdout().write_all(data).unwrap();
        Ok(data.len())
    })})
    .and_then(|_| easy.perform())
    .and_then(|_| easy.response_code())
    .iter()
    .for_each(|response_code| println!("{}", response_code));
}
```

Since `Result` is iterable, we can turn it into an iterator and use `for_each` to print its `Ok` variant payload if present.
Alternatively, you can assign the result to a variable and use `if let` with pattern matching for the printing step:

```
let response_code = easy.url("https://www.rust-lang.org/")
.and_then(|_| {
    easy.write_function(|data| {
    stdout().write_all(data).unwrap();
    Ok(data.len())
})})
.and_then(|_| easy.perform())
.and_then(|_| easy.response_code());

if let Ok(response_code) = response_code {
    println!("{}", response_code);
}
```

The idea here is that once you have a `Result` value, you can still apply a function to it that, in turn, returns another `Result`<sup>X</sup>, and the whole result will still be a single `Result` that sequences both of them. You can keep performing operations on the value inside the `Result` without that value leaving the `Result` wrapped around itself.

There are some limitations, though. For example, regarding the inner `unwrap`:

```
stdout().write_all(data).unwrap();
Ok(data.len())
```

The second type argument (i.e., the error type) of these `Result`s are different: `Error` and `WriteError`. So, you would need a way to map an `Error` into a [`WriteError`](https://docs.rs/curl/0.4.44/curl/easy/enum.WriteError.html) to get rid of the `unwrap` through [`Result<T,E>::map_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err). For example:

```
easy.write_function(|data| {
stdout().write_all(data)
.map(|_| data.len())
.map_err(|_err| curl::easy::WriteError::Pause)
```

---

<sup>X</sup> This can also be done with functions that don't return a `Result` through [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map)

Comment: I would heavily favor `if let Ok(..)` over `.iter().for_each()` when working with errors because it's way more straight forward and obvious what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), curl::Error> {
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://www.rust-lang.org/")?;
    easy.write_function(|data| {
        stdout().write_all(data).unwrap();
        Ok(data.len())
    })?;
    easy.perform()?;

    println!("{}", easy.response_code()?);
    Ok(())
}
```

Or some other error handling. The `unwrap` in `write_function` is not trivial to remove as it'll really depend how you want to handle those conditions: [the callback](https://docs.rs/curl/latest/curl/easy/struct.Easy.html#method.write_function) can only return a [`WriteError`](https://docs.rs/curl/latest/curl/easy/enum.WriteError.html), which just tells curl to stop reading. So you need cooperation between the caller and the callback to handle the reporting of non-trivial conditions. Or you can just ignore the entire thing:

```
let _ = stdout().write_all(data);
```

or

```
drop(std::io::stdout().write_all(data));
```

however that will suppress (ignore) failure signaling entirely, so it should only be used if you truly do not care about a failure of the call.

You could also use a more explicit form of composition like [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then), or use [let else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html) to guard instead of panic-ing, although these options will obviously be more verbose.